# Unexpected behavior of FindClusters

Tags: random, cluster-analysis

This is my code created by 10.4ï¼

```
SeedRandom[2]
p = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];
sortPoint[p_] := 
 Module[{order = Last[FindShortestTour[p]]}, 
  If[RandomReal[] < .5, p[[Rest[order]]], p[[order]]]]
Graphics[line = Line /@ sortPoint /@ FindClusters[p, 5]]
```

I got following result

[image]

When I run it in 11.0.0 or 11.0.1,I will get

[image]

When the version change,the result will be different.Is it noraml?Or is this a bug?

Comment: Do you get the same for `p` on both versions?

Comment: `FindClusters` had many changes, are you sure it isn't caused by that?  I didn't try.

Comment: Also, I see you are using the second argument of `FindClusters`. This no longer works properly in v11.0 unless you explicitly select a method that supports specifying the number of clusters, e.g. `Method -> "KMeans"`.  I did report this problem during the beta period for v11, but it wasn't fixed either for release, or for the 11.0.1 update.

Comment: @Szabolcs I realize this is question about `FindClusters`,so this behavior should consider as a bug?And as I try,the `Method -> "KMeans"` cannot give a same result with 10.4.

Comment: I don't know ... sorry, I didn't investigate in detail, I was just giving some tips that I thought may be relevant.

Comment: @Feyre I'm sorry,I have no 10.4.1 or before version.So I don't know exactly they are same or not.

Comment: `Length[line]` is 5 here, so it's not the bug I mentioned.  `FindClusters` may be using a different method by default.  That doesn't mean that the result is wrong because the problem this function solves isn't precisely defined.   To get the same result, it may be useful to try explicit method settings.

Comment: KMeans is not a deterministic algorithm and may well return different answers to the same problem, even with the same k value.